# How to implement ad hoc connection on android?

Tags: android, adhoc

it is posible to implenet in application ad hoc connection? I want to write app which need to connect to ad hoc network, but i know that android no support ad hoc networks. Can i do application which find and connect to ad hoc network?

Answer (score 2):

There is Lib developed an ad-hoc library that may be included to any Android app that need to run on a mobile ad-hoc network. The library comprises a routing protocol module (based on AODV) and a setup module for creating and stopping an ad-hoc network on supported Android devices.

```
http://code.google.com/p/adhoc-on-android/
```

I hope this might help you.

Comment: Thanks, i hope it will help me.